# Scala extraction/pattern matching using a companion object

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

The below code is taken from Spark SQL. It performs extraction, but the `castType` is a companion object - one would call it as `TypeCast.castTo("abc", StringType)`.
Could somebody please explain how pattern matching works with companion objects under the hood?

```
private[csv] def castTo(datum: String, castType: DataType): Any = {                                 
  castType match {                                                                                  
    case _: ByteType => datum.toByte                                                                
    case _: ShortType => datum.toShort
    case _: IntegerType => datum.toInt
    case _: LongType => datum.toLong
    case _: FloatType => datum.toFloat
    case _: DoubleType => datum.toDouble                                                            
    case _: BooleanType => datum.toBoolean                                                          
    case _: DecimalType => new BigDecimal(datum.replaceAll(",", ""))                                
    case _: TimestampType => Timestamp.valueOf(datum)                                               
    case _: DateType => Date.valueOf(datum)                                                         
    case _: StringType => datum
    case _ => throw new RuntimeException(s"Unsupported type: ${castType.typeName}")                 
  } 
}
```

ADDED:
Based on my understanding extractin/pattern matching is usually implemented by the unapply method of the companion object. This is an example of how case classes are [implemented under the hood](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/11/21/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-1-extractors.html)

```
 trait User {
  def name: String
}
class FreeUser(val name: String) extends User
class PremiumUser(val name: String) extends User

object FreeUser {
  def unapply(user: FreeUser): Option[String] = Some(user.name)
}
object PremiumUser {
  def unapply(user: PremiumUser): Option[String] = Some(user.name)
}
```

I don't really understand how the same thing can be done for companion classes

Comment: What do you mean by "how exactly does it work"? What this pattern matching is? How it is called? Haven't used Spark, but I would just add a note that `private[csv]` means that it shouldn't be used by you, so doing `TypeCast.castTo(...)` is not possible from other packages.

Comment: re: private - not planing to use it, just trying to understand how it works

Comment: I know what pattern matching is, but usually castType would be an object of some type, in this case it's a companion object. So the question is how does pattern matching work with companion objects.

Comment: Companion objects are just objects at the end of the day, so I guess the answer is that you can pattern match on them the same way as with any other objects or values. The only difference is that they are singleton and you don't have to keep creating instances of them. If this does not answer your question then can you please clarify? I'm afraid I don't quite get what you don't understand.

Comment: @Akos Krivachy - thanks! My main confusion is that pattern matching is implemented using the unapply method of the companion object. Where is the pattern matching logic for the companion object is implemented (since it doesn't have a companion object)

Comment: Unapply is used in extractor patterns. It's upto the implementor of the type to provide an apply/unapply method.

Comment: I.K. is right, you seem to be confused on where `unapply` is used. For an example `2 match { case 2 => println("yay") }` does not use `unapply` even though it is a pattern match.

Comment: Have a look at [this workaround](http://queirozf.com/entries/slick-error-message-value-tupled-is-not-a-member-of-object) I've applied when using Slick with Case Classes for which a companion object was also defined. Maybe it rings some bells.

Answer (score 0):

I have never worked with Spark, so I cannot answer with specific Spark knowledge.

But the pattern matching in your example seems to be ordinary type based pattern matching.

`castType` is an instance of the type `DataType` that has several subclasses e.g. `ByteType`. The pattern matching just tests whether the `castType` object belongs to the specific class (e.g. `ByteType`).

Because there are just singleton instances of the several sub-types, the matching does not need to provide the matches instance at all. That is why the match uses just a placeholder `_`.

Comment: the this is, that castType is not an instance of DataType (or any of it's subclasses) - it is a companion object. It's call as TypeCast.castTo("abc", StringType) (not TypeCast.castTo("abc", new StringType))